# ClassicThesis TOC headlines

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, classicthesis

Why the headlines in the TOC are in `\normalfont` and not in `\spacedlowsmallcaps` as the rest of the document? How can I make it `\spacedlowsmallcaps`?

```
\documentclass[%
                headinclude,%
                footinclude,%
                10pt,%
%               openany%
                ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[%
            pdfspacing%
            ]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\end{document}
```

---

Finally I have used the following:

```
\renewcommand*{\tocbasic@listhead}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{tocbasic@listhead@\@currext}{%
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname chapter\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\def\csname tocbasic@listhead@\@currext\endcsname##1{%
        \iftocfeature{\@currext}{leveldown}{%
          \iftocfeature{\@currext}{numbered}{%
            \subsection[##1]{##1}%
          }{%
            \subsection*{##1}%
            \ifx\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\else\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{##1}}\fi
            \iftocfeature{\@currext}{totoc}{%
              \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{##1}%
            }{}%
          }%
        }{%
          \iftocfeature{\@currext}{numbered}{%
            \section[##1]{##1}%
          }{%
            \section*{##1}%
            \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{##1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{##1}}%
            \iftocfeature{\@currext}{totoc}{%
              \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{##1}%
            }{}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    \else
      \expandafter\def\csname tocbasic@listhead@\@currext\endcsname##1{%
        \iftocfeature{\@currext}{leveldown}{%
          \iftocfeature{\@currext}{numbered}{%
            \section{##1}%
          }{%
            \section*{##1}%
            \iftocfeature{\@currext}{totoc}{%
              \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{##1}%
            }{}%
            \ifx\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\else\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{##1}}\fi
          }%
        }{%
          \iftocfeature{\@currext}{numbered}{%
            \chapter[##1]{##1}%
          }{%
            \chapter*{##1}%
            \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{##1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{##1}}%
            \iftocfeature{\@currext}{totoc}{%
              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{##1}%
            }{}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    \fi
  }{}%
  \csname tb@@beforehead@hook\endcsname
  \csname tb@\@currext @beforehead@hook\endcsname
  \csname tocbasic@listhead@\@currext\endcsname{#1}%
  \csname tb@\@currext @afterhead@hook\endcsname
  \csname tb@@afterhead@hook\endcsname
}
```

Comment: Because ClassicThesis is buggy?

Comment: @egreg yes, and it's a shame because I really like some of the features it provides.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm trying to make a package that fix all these problems and that provide all that the normal classicthesis don't provide already from default. Soon it will be finished and then I'll tell you ; D

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The headlines in the classicthesis.pdf of the TOC are in smallcaps. What am I missing...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This patch seems to give the expected result; it should work also for lists of figures and tables.

```
\documentclass[ 
  headinclude, 
  footinclude,%
  10pt,%
%  openany%
 ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  pdfspacing 
 ]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\tocbasic@listhead}{\MakeMarkcase}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
...
```

[image]

You might also try the following:

```
\renewcommand{\MakeMarkcase}[1]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}
```

Comment: I have finally used the code in my question...